# Draw group bar plot without reshaping data

Tags: r

I have following data.table

```
   Golds Bronzes Silvers Country
1:   930     639     728     USA
2:   247     320     284     GER
3:   192     234     212     FRA
```

and I want to draw a group bar plot with `country` in the `x-axis` and number of medals in the `y-axis`. For each country, the graph should have 3 bars indicating Gold, Silver & Bronze. Is there a way to do that with ggplot wnad without melting data.?

Comment: Why are you opposed to temporary data transformation?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am not opposing, but I feel like this is too simple for melting and casting for that kind of task. Just my thought. Curious about any other way.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `barplot` function accepts a matrix of heights:

```
barplot(as.matrix(x[, 1:3]), beside = TRUE,
        legend.text = x$Country)
```

**Update:** To plot it the other way around you can transpose the matrix:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(x[, 1:3])),
        beside = TRUE,
        names.arg = x$Country,
        legend.text = names(x)[1:3])
```

Comment: This answer is not incorrect, but it flips my requirement. I want to plot the country in x axis and number of medals in y. bars should be different medal types

Answer (score 0):

## create a data frame

```
test <- data.frame(Country = c("USA", "GER", "FRA"), 
               Golds = c(930, 247, 192), 
               Bronzes = c(639, 320, 234),
               Silvers = c(728, 284, 212))
```

## plot in one step

```
    test %>%
     gather(key = "award", value = "number", -Country)  %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = number, color = award, fill = award)) + 
     geom_col(position = "dodge")
```